# yocto open embedded recipe using host perl install

Tags: yocto, openembedded

I'm on yocto (version morty) and I'm seeing an issue with a recipe I'm trying to create for heimdal (https://github.com/heimdal/heimdal). During configuration, it ends up using host's install of perl rather than the perl build dependency. So it will work on any machine that has perl and the modules installed but I don't think this is how yocto is supposed to work (correct me if I'm wrong).

My guess is this is an error in either Heimdal's configure.ac file, or a bug with autotools.  I'm not super savy with autotools, was wondering if someone could confirm this?  Here's a direct link to their configure.ac

https://github.com/heimdal/heimdal/blob/master/configure.ac

Of course this could also be an error in my recipe too:

```
SUMMARY = "A Kerberos 6 Implementation"

SRC_URI = "\
  git://github.com/heimdal/heimdal.git;protocol=https;branch=master \
"
SRCREV = "e21866f7a29ab9d0fcf69efddaec6f758faf7494"
LICENSE = "BSD-3-Clause"
S = "${WORKDIR}/git"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE;md5=2580e0b4d85feafcd5c339f5be3c8229"

DEPENDS = "perl json-perl"

inherit autotools

PACKAGECONFIG = "pk-init mmap"

# Features
PACKAGECONFIG[afs-support] = "--enable-afs-support,--disable-afs-support"
PACKAGECONFIG[kcm] = "--enable-kcm,--disable-kcm"
PACKAGECONFIG[otp] = "--enable-otp,--disable-otp"
PACKAGECONFIG[pk-init] = "--enable-pk-init,--disable-pk-init"
PACKAGECONFIG[heimdal-documentation] = "--enable-heimdal-documentation,--disable-heimdal-documentation"
PACKAGECONFIG[mmap] = "--enable-mmap,--disable-mmap"
PACKAGECONFIG[sqlist-cache] = "--enable-sqlist-cache,--disable-sqlist-cache"
PACKAGECONFIG[ndmb-db] = "--enable-ndmb-db,--disable-ndmb-db"
PACKAGECONFIG[mdb-db] = "--enable-mdb-db,--disable-mdb-db"
PACKAGECONFIG[osfc2] = "--enable-osfc2,--disable-osfc2"

# Packages
PACKAGECONFIG[berkley-db] = "--with-berkley-db,--without-berkley-db"
PACKAGECONFIG[ipv6] = "--with-ipv6,--without-ipv6"
```

Also I'm using open-embedded's (version morty) default perl recipe and this json-perl recipe:

```
DESCRIPTION = "This module is a thin wrapper for JSON::XS-compatible modules with a few \
additional features. All the backend modules convert a Perl data structure \
to a JSON text as of RFC4627 (which we know is obsolete but we still stick \
to; see below for an option to support part of RFC7159) and vice versa. \
This module uses JSON::XS by default, and when JSON::XS is not available, \
this module falls back on JSON::PP, which is in the Perl core since 5.14. \
If JSON::PP is not available either, this module then falls back on \
JSON::backportPP (which is actually JSON::PP in a different .pm file) \
bundled in the same distribution as this module. You can also explicitly \
specify to use Cpanel::JSON::XS, a fork of JSON::XS by Reini Urban."

SECTION = "libs"
LICENSE = "Artisticv1 | GPLv1+"
PR = "r0"

MAINTAINER= "Poky <poky@yoctoproject.org>"
HOMEPAGE=   "https://metacpan.org/release/JSON"

LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/Artistic-1.0;md5=cda03bbdc3c1951996392b872397b798 \
file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/GPL-1.0;md5=e9e36a9de734199567a4d769498f743d"

SRC_URI = "https://cpan.metacpan.org/authors/id/I/IS/ISHIGAKI/JSON-2.97001.tar.gz"

SRC_URI[md5sum] = "693d6ff167496362f8ec6c3c5b8ba5ee"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "e277d9385633574923f48c297e1b8acad3170c69fa590e31fa466040fc6f8f5a"

S = "${WORKDIR}/JSON-${PV}"

inherit cpan allarch

BBCLASSEXTEND = "native"
```

Comment: sorry to write 4 years later, but are you abel to share this yocto source? I currently have the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Perl using **nativeperl** as perl binary, so, I guess, you should patch projects' *configure.ac* to change value of PERL variable with AC_PATH_PROG, check [this](http://lists.openembedded.org/pipermail/openembedded-core/2011-August/047000.html)

Also, you need to [have](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.8/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#ref-classes-perlnative)

```
inherit perlnative
```

Comment: Adding "inherit perlnative" appears to have done the trick.  Thanks for the help.